# I first made a change in the Settings app,but I failed to get the newest NSUserDefaults values when my App enter foreground later

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I first made a change in the Settings app,
and when my app enter foreground later, this method will be called:

```
-(void)appWillEnterForeground:(NSNotification *) notification{
    //get standardUserDefaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //save all modification
    [defaults synchronize];
    //change the UI
    [self refreshFields];

}
```

the method below just refresh the UI

```
-(void)refreshFields{
    //get standardUserDefaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    //get all the preference value
    self.nameLabel.text=[defaults stringForKey:@"name_preference"];
}
```

I found that the value I get is the old value instead of the value I just set in the Settings app. 
but when I restart app it will get the newest defaults value

i just want Once I changed the setting in Settings,my App will get the change when the app enter foreground again.

Comment: Why not set the text to nameLabel directly?

Comment: thanks to your comment,i just tried your advice,but it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you log the string for key 'name_preference'? You can also check  the pilst file created by NSUserDefaults in sandbox.

Comment: i found that the plist file in  .../Library/Preferences will change simultaneously wilth my modification in Settings, but the values get by  `[defaults dictionaryRepresentation]` are still old values

Answer (score 0):

After I upgraded my Xcode to the newest 8.1 , and using the newest simulator provided by Xcode8.1, this problem has gone, all thing works well!
So I guess it's the question of the old Xcode6 beta and simulator.